# Google play store - test iab without paying for dev account

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I want to test in-app billing with Google Play Store, however it seems I need to pay 25$ to register a test-app just to make this testing possible (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html).

I've looked around a bunch and can't find any alternatives but most threads I find are out-dated, so I want to know if there is an option available at the moment that allows me to make a test-ID for billing without having to pay the registration fee for the developer console (https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Developer account is required to test IAB since you are interacting directly with Google Play. There are "Static Responses" which you can call without uploading your app to the Developer Console, but to use those your test device must be logged into a developer account. More info can be found in the docs:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

So yes, you must pay the $25 and register a developer account. But why wouldn't you anyway? If you are learning to code Android, chances are you have the intent of releasing an app at some point. So why not just opt in now and get access to all the Developer tools you need?

Comment: I will, but doesnt hurt to ask to check for alternatives :) Thanks for info

Comment: No harsh tone intended :) More of a logical conclusion than a scolding. Glad it answered your question.